# Как сделать так, чтобы высота блока видео с ютуба определялась размерами экрана?

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe, youtube

Есть блок с зацикленным видео с ютуба [Фидл](https://jsfiddle.net/mfh26hvc/)

```
<iframe class="inner" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="1" title="YouTube video player" width="100%" height="100%" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/TP1U4fySrCI?playlist=TP1U4fySrCI&iv_load_policy=3&enablejsapi=1&disablekb=1&autoplay=1&controls=0&showinfo=0&rel=0&loop=1&wmode=transparent&origin=http%3A%2F%2Flike2.likemedia.by&widgetid=1"
      id="widget2" style="max-width: 1000%;  width: 100%; height: 785.25px;"></iframe>
```

Как сделать так, чтобы в зависимости от разрешения экрана высота сама подстраивалась, не обрезалась картинка и не возникало черных полос?

Comment: у вас видео такого размера отснято и монитор здесь не причем, скорее всего вы хотите выставить размер плеера под размер снятого видео... а это уже не под область монитора (если сомневаетесь в моих словах - подумайте как ваше видео будет смотреться на больших мониторах) выставить размер iframe под монитор это одно, а вычислить размер показываемого в плеере видео это другое

Comment: @Jenyokcoder нет, это не видео так снято - посмотрите пожалуйста внимательно уже найденные решения

Comment: если это не видео такого размера (что за черные полоски сверху и снизу?) это риторический вопрос, дабы избежать демагогии...

Comment: @Jenyokcoder заданная высота `height: 785.25px;`
если ее не задавать, то видео вовсе не отобразится на странице

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решений 2: 
1 - воспользоваться библиотекой [fitvids](http://fitvidsjs.com/)
2 - с помощью css-трюка - [фидл](https://jsfiddle.net/mfh26hvc/1/)

```css
.videoWrapper {
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 56.25%;
  /* 16:9 */
  padding-top: 25px;
  height: 0;
}

.videoWrapper iframe {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="videoWrapper">
  <iframe class="inner" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="1" title="YouTube video player" width="100%" height="100%" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/TP1U4fySrCI?playlist=TP1U4fySrCI&iv_load_policy=3&enablejsapi=1&disablekb=1&autoplay=1&controls=0&showinfo=0&rel=0&loop=1&wmode=transparent&origin=http%3A%2F%2Flike2.likemedia.by&widgetid=1"></iframe></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно сделать так:

```
document.getElementById('widget2').height = window.innerHeight;
```

Comment: вот так? https://jsfiddle.net/mfh26hvc/3/
но, это несколько не то - выглядит адекватнее, но черные полосы никуда не исчезли. решение внизу

Answer (score -1):

Попробуйте `vh` и `vw`:

```
height: 100vh;
width: 100vw;
```

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?